# Searching for multiple strings in Azure AD groups

Tags: powershell, azure-active-directory

We have Azure AD groups with the following naming convention: *Department_GroupName_Membership type (with three options: visitor/member/owner)*. I need to be able to add users to all groups from Department_XY with the membership type "Member". I.e. something like `Department_XY_{GroupName}_Member`.

I cannot figure out how to retrieve a list of such groups. ODATA filter clauses that should be taken by `-Filter`parameter of `Get_AzureAdGroup`Cmdlet work strangely.

For example `Get-AzureADGroup -Filter "startswith(DisplayName, 'Department_XY')"` works fine, however, `Get-AzureADGroup -Filter "endswith(DisplayName, 'Member')` throws an error.

So I assume there is some better way how to do that?

I have AzureAD module installed.

`.....`

Comment: Have you checked out `-Filter`?  There's an example here: https://learn.microsoft.com/bs-latn-ba/azure/active-directory/users-groups-roles/groups-settings-v2-cmdlets

Comment: This isn't working...```-Filter``` doesn't seem to support ```-contain``` operator so it can only be used for exact match.

Comment: On the one hand you say that the membertype can be any of these **visitor/member/owner** (note: `member` singular), but on the other hand you are trying to use `Members` (plural)

Comment: So, `-Filter` appears to take an ODATA filter clause, which I don't have experience with, but `substringof` may work (https://www.odata.org/documentation/odata-version-2-0/uri-conventions/).  I think understanding the ODATA syntax for the query is the key.

Comment: ```substringof``` isn't working. Neither does  ```endswith```. The only String function that worked was ```startswith```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`-SearchString` appears to not accept any wildcards and only searches the beginning of the `DisplayName` values, i.e. an effective `.StartsWith(string)`.

`-Filter` uses the OData v3 query language (unless it has been updated to v4). However, for whatever reason, many functions are not available including `endswith()` and `substringof()`.

You can use a combination of `-SearchString` and `Where-Object` or `-Filter` and `Where-Object` to create an efficient query.

```
Get-AzureAdGroup -SearchString 'Department_XY' -All $true |
    Where-Object { $_.DisplayName.EndsWith('Member') }
```

Comment: This is the more efficient answer since the first command before the pipe will return a smaller list of groups that you can then iterate through to get the endswith.

Comment: I would also add "-All $true" to Get-AzureAdGroup in case there are more than 100 groups with the name Department_XY.

Comment: @MerillFernando, Thanks for the suggestion. I made the update.

Answer (score 10):

To expand on [@AdminOfThings answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59612219/2150063), and others about the `-Fliter` parameter, let's do an investigation into what's going on....

Using: AzureAD version 2.0.2.76

From the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/get-azureadgroup?view=azureadps-2.0) `Get-AzureADGroup` `-Filter` parameter uses the "[OData v3.0 protocol](https://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata/v4.0/errata03/os/complete/part2-url-conventions/odata-v4.0-errata03-os-part2-url-conventions-complete.html#_Toc453752358)" (I use big air quotes here deliberately). But when you *actually* try to use more advanced filter parameters like `substringof()` and `endswith()` we get the error:

> ```
> Get-AzureADGroup : Error occurred while executing GetGroups
> Code: Request_UnsupportedQuery
> Message: Unsupported Query.
> ```

So, that didn't work. Ok, let's switch to using the `-SearchString` parameter, which "should" (big air quotes) perform a [`GetVague`](https://github.com/Azure/azure-docs-powershell-azuread/blob/master/azureadps-2.0/AzureAD/Get-AzureADGroup.md) operation a.k.a. an OData `$search` operation (which in this case, we try to  misuse as a `$substring()` operation). So let's try:

```
Get-AzureADGroup -SearchString "Department_XY"
```

Returns results as expected. Now let's try to search for something at the end of the `DisplayName`, "Member":

```
Get-AzureADGroup -SearchString "Member"
```

> ```
> No Results.
> ```

This means that what is actually happening is it is performing a `$filter=startswith()` query, and not a `$search` query as expected.

The [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/get-azureadgroup?view=azureadps-2.0) also say that the `-SearchString` doesn't accept wildcard characters, nor the `-Filter` parameter, and the [OData protocol](https://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata/v4.0/errata03/os/complete/part2-url-conventions/odata-v4.0-errata03-os-part2-url-conventions-complete.html#_Toc453752358) for filtering does not use wildcards. It only does straight character matching. So that's why trying:

```
Get-AzureADGroup -SearchString "Department_XY*"
```

Does not return any results. This is because we are not searching for anything starting with "`Department_XY`" we are actually explicitly searching for anything starting with "`Department_XY*`", which treats the *asterisk* at the end, as a part of the name.

So onto the question of *why* does this not work as expected? We are used to using PowerShell cmdlets with wildcards, regex, and crazy filtering options. We essentially have been spoiled with the Active Directory PowerShell module and operations that we can perform on it. To fully understand the *why*, we have to understand *what* is going on, when we run `Get-AzureADGroup`?

Essentially, what the [AzureAD module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/?view=azureadps-2.0) is, is a giant PowerShell wrapper that makes [Microsoft Graph API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/use-the-api) calls and abstracts the fetching/setting/security/token complexity away from us. That is why `-Filter` uses the [OData v3.0 protocol](https://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata/v4.0/errata03/os/complete/part2-url-conventions/odata-v4.0-errata03-os-part2-url-conventions-complete.html#_Toc453752358) syntax rather than something more "PowerShell-y" like wildcards/regex. That is why the full error message has a `HttpStatusCode: BadRequest` in it:

> ```
> Get-AzureADGroup : Error occurred while executing GetGroups
> Code: Request_UnsupportedQuery
> Message: Unsupported Query.
> RequestId: 3455cecd3-bcbc-4257-9be6-69e05a123e26
> DateTimeStamp: Wed, 01 Jan 2020 01:01:01 GMT
> HttpStatusCode: BadRequest
> HttpStatusDescription: Bad Request
> HttpResponseStatus: Completed
> ```

---

## Microsoft Graph API

Let's explore the [Microsoft Graph API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/use-the-api) and figure out what is going on. To do this, let's use the [Microsoft Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer). Sign in, grant permissions needed, including `Group.Read.All` permissions needed to perform the queries.

When we perform the `-Filter` query what we are executing is:

**PowerShell:**

```
Get-AzureADGroup -Filter "startswith(DisplayName, 'Department_XY')"
```

**Microsoft Graph API Call:**

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups?$filter=startswith(displayName,'Department_XY')
```

Both operations return our expected rows of data.

So, let's try an OData filter query with `endswith()`:

**PowerShell:**

```
Get-AzureADGroup -Filter "endswith(DisplayName, 'Member')"
```

> ```
> Get-AzureADGroup : Error occurred while executing GetGroups
> Code: Request_UnsupportedQuery
> Message: Unsupported Query.
> RequestId: 3455cecd3-bcbc-4257-9be6-69e05a123e26
> DateTimeStamp: Wed, 01 Jan 2020 01:01:01 GMT
> HttpStatusCode: BadRequest
> HttpStatusDescription: Bad Request
> HttpResponseStatus: Completed
> ```

**Microsoft Graph API Call:**

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups?$filter=endswith(DisplayName, 'Member')
```

> ```
> {
>     "error": {
>         "code": "Request_UnsupportedQuery",
>         "message": "Unsupported Query.",
>         "innerError": {
>             "request-id": "19ab3d69-77f7-45ea-b871-4dd518509193",
>             "date": "2020-01-08T17:53:07"
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```

Both methods give us the same "Unsupported Query." errors.

When we take a look at the API docs about the [filter query parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/query-parameters#filter-parameter) we see that only a subset of OData query filters are supported, and to top it off, the Note at the end of the filter section says:

> Note: The following `$filter` operators are not supported for Azure AD
>   resources: `ne`, `gt`, `ge`, `lt`, `le`, and `not`. The `contains` string operator
>   is currently not supported on any Microsoft Graph resources.

This means that we are left with three possible `filter` operations:

- equals (`eq`)
- `startswith`
- `any`

This means that there is currently no way of filtering a group name any other way besides an exact match, or `startswith`, *at the Microsoft Graph source*.

Well hold on! What about `-SearchString`? this would equate to the `$search` OData query parameter. It works in PowerShell, why not Graph API?

**PowerShell:**

```
Get-AzureADGroup -SearchString "Department_XY"
```

> ```
> ...Returns Group Results...
> ```

**Microsoft Graph API Call:**

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups?$search="Department_XY"
```

> ```
> {
>     "error": {
>         "code": "Request_UnsupportedQuery",
>         "message": "This query is not supported.",
>         "innerError": {
>             "request-id": "67fe0362-d78d-4de3-b52a-c8bfce109f98",
>             "date": "2020-01-08T18:23:10"
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```

What's going on? Looking at the docs for [search query parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/query-parameters#search-parameter), at the top, there's the Note:

> Note: You can currently search only message and person collections. A
>   `$search` request returns up to 250 results. You cannot use `$filter` or
>   `$orderby` in a search request.

Which means that searching by groups is not implemented. What the PowerShell cmdlet is doing is providing a `-SearchString` parameter with the intention that it can be hooked up to an appropriate `search` query parameter in the future, but for right now, it "fakes" it with a `$filter=startswith()` query. Once the Microsoft Graph API supports more query parameters and more updates, this "faking" may change.

---

So, we have thoroughly exhausted all options for filtering at the source. We have to do all the filtering on our PowerShell client end. We can:

- Be smart and at least use [@AdminOfThings answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59612219/2150063) to pre-filter the groups based on the start string.
- Use `-SearchString` because then we don't have explicitly fiddle with filter query formats.
- As [@MerillFernando](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59547039/searching-for-multiple-strings-in-azure-ad-groups#comment105436540_59557634) mentions, we have to specify the `-All $true` parameter because, as we know, it is making requests to the Microsoft Graph API, and it only returns the top 100 entries by default.

  - To expand on why [@AllenWu answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59557634/2150063) wasn't working, when you run a `Get-AzureADGroup` without the `-All $true` switch, it will only return 100 groups. These 100 groups are "randomly" selected. If you have 1000's of groups, it is very likely that the groups you are trying to select may not be in that first batch of 100 groups you get.
- I, personally, like to save the entries to a variable so that I can run multiple different queries/filters until I get what I want without making multiple API requests.
- Once it's in a variable inside PowerShell, we can use our favorite filtering/regex methods to match what we want.
- In this use case, use `EndsWith()` for filtering above other filtering methods like `-like` or regex. I think [@AdminOfThings](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59612219/2150063) has the right idea to filter this way because the function will parse the string backwards, which would operate an order of magnitude faster and more efficient than a `-like` filter which would have to handle the entire string with each evaluation.

So, TLDR. The code you end up with is:

```
$groups = Get-AzureADGroup -SearchString 'Department_XY' -All $true
$groups | Where-Object { $_.DisplayName.EndsWith('Member') }
```

Comment: This should be marked as the "real" answer. Thank you @HAL9256!

Answer (score 1):

This one worked for me like a charm...
**(You can use Wildcard anywhere in your search string)**

```
Get-AzureAdGroup -All $True | Where-Object { $_.DisplayName -like ('*first*second*') }
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on my understanding, you want to get the AD groups whose names have the following format: `Department_A_{GroupName}_Members`.

So you can use `Where-Object` statement when you need to filter a list.

In this case, try the following cmd:

```
Get-AzureADGroup | Where-Object {$_.DisplayName -like 'Department_A_*_Members'}
```

Comment: Hi Allen, you have the correct understanding. The code you proposed didn't work. It displays nothing.

Comment: @DDEX The cmd should work. Please check the name format of your group. In the command you provided at the beginning, the group name is "* _Members". But after you updated the question now it becomes "* _Member". If so, you should use `Get-AzureADGroup | Where-Object {$_.DisplayName -like 'Department_XY_*_Member'}`. If it still doesn't work, please add a screenshot of your group name.

Comment: This is not working because of the same issue as the other answer. For this to work you need to change the first line to 'Get-AzureADGroup -All $true'. If not you will be searching just the first 100 groups. However this won't be efficient if you have a very large tenant with thousands of groups since you are first downloading all the groups and then filtering them locally. This can take a while.

Answer (score -1):

Here's a way to filter using select-object. I put it into a variable in case we need to use it later. I added an -and so you can check for both dept and for "member". You can replace *Department_XY* with your groupname enclosed with the wildcards too if you want to do that instead. ('*groupname*')

```
$groups = Get-AzureADGroup -All $true
$groups | Select-Object {$_.DisplayName -like '*Department_XY*' -and $_.DisplayName -like '*member*'}
```

Comment: For this to work you need to change the first line to 'Get-AzureADGroup -All $true'. If not you will be searching just the first 100 groups. However this won't be efficient if you have a very large tenant with thousands of groups since you are first downloading all the groups and then filtering them locally. This can take a while.

Answer (score -1):

Try with option below. An example is given for /user in MS documentation. I tried with groups and it worked.

```
graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups?$count=true&$search="displayName:Finance"&ConsistencyLevel=eventual
```